# How to Open a Web Page in Kiosk Mode ANDROID

Tags: android, html, kiosk

I want to use Android Tablet to show a web page in Kiosk mode ( The user can't close the page, no address bar .. )
So is there any simple solution to do that ?

Comment: Using webview may help you

Comment: Android L has built-in kiosk mode capability, but for every other version kiosk mode is a massive pain in the rear to implement. (Bitter experience speaking here.) You can sort of hack aspects of it for certain devices--I've got it working sort of on a Samsung Galaxy Notepro--but for the most part it's quite difficult to do. Can you give more context on your application?

Comment: There's no application, I want to display a web site in kiosk mode in android Tablet, and the user of the tablet can't close or return to main menu

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I founded the opensource Webconverger Web kiosk project.

https://github.com/webconverger/android is an opensource implementation of an Android 5.0 app that does just that. You could remove the close button, but the close button simply reloads the configured homepage.

Android 5.0's [screen pinning](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenPinning) locks it all down. If you must run on older Android <5 versions, have a look at [good collection of Android kiosk mode hacks](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/).